# Moving multiple files with find and tar on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, find, tar, travis-ci

I am trying to move certain `.ipynb` files from one directory to another using this command:

`find . -name "*failed.ipynb" -print0 | xargs -0 tar cvf "-" | (cd ./fails ; tar xfp "-")`

The command works fine on OS X and CentOS, but when run on Travis CI on an Ubuntu machine it fails where there are spaces in filenames.

I thought that the `-print0` and `-0` options should deal with this, is there something else that I'm doing wrong?

EDIT
The output looks like this:

```
$ source ./scripts/runipy.sh
Processing science/Transients/Followup Observatories.ipynb
science/Transients/Followup Observatories.ipynb failed.

The following notebooks failed
tar: ./science/Transients/Followup: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Observatories.ipynb-failed.ipynb: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
```

It's failing where an `.ipynb` file has a space in the filename.

Thanks

Comment: What does the failure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `cpio` instead?  It reads filenames from stdio, so there are no problems with spaces.  (Though there might be with newlines, in which case there is the `-0` option.)

```
find . -name "*failed.ipynb" | cpio -pd ./fails
```